# \DeclarePairedDelimiter with \left and \right

Tags: delimiters

Why does this not work?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
 \newcommand{\DeclareAutoPairedDelimiter}[3]{\DeclarePairedDelimiter{#1}{\left#2}{\right#3}}
 \DeclareAutoPairedDelimiter{\p}{(}{)}  % but works fine if I say \DeclarePairedDelimiter
 $\p{2} \p*{4}$
\end{document}
```

The error I get is

```
./Test.tex:7: Extra }, or forgotten \right
./Test.tex:7: Missing } inserted
./Test.tex:7: Missing delimiter (. inserted)
./Test.tex:7: Missing delimiter (. inserted)
./Test.tex:7: Extra }, or forgotten \right
./Test.tex:7: Missing } inserted
```

Comment: Why should it work?

Comment: @egreg: What do you mean? Is it not obvious that `\DeclareAutoPairedDelimiter` should result in the same thing as `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It can't work, because doing

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\p}{\left(}{\right)}
```

is wrong.

You probably want something like

```
\newcommand{\DeclareAutoPairedDelimiter}[3]{%
  \expandafter\DeclarePairedDelimiter\csname Auto\string#1\endcsname{#2}{#3}%
  \DeclareRobustCommand{#1}{\csname Auto\string#1\endcsname*}}
```

You appear to share the commonly held belief that always adding `\left` and `\right` is good. It isn't.

A complete example, with a more robust version that avoids possible problems with `\escapechar`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\DeclareAutoPairedDelimiter}[3]{%
  \expandafter\DeclarePairedDelimiter\csname Auto\string#1\endcsname{#2}{#3}%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\DeclareRobustCommand{\noexpand#1}{%
      \expandafter\noexpand\csname Auto\string#1\endcsname*}}%
  \x}

\DeclareAutoPairedDelimiter{\p}{(}{)}

\show\p

\begin{document}
\[
\p{\frac{a}{b}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh shoot, I actually just realized I would need `\lparen` and `\rparen` if I wanted to do literally what I had (which I realize may not be a good idea, but that's not the question here)... huh, interesting. +1 thanks

Comment: (explanation) Roughly speaking, we know that after `DeclarePairedDelimiter{\Autop}{(}{)}`, then `\Autop*{...}` will resize the delimiter, so we do that and then `\DeclareRebustCommand{\p}{\Autop*}` so that `\p{...}` expands to `\Autop*{...}`