# "Missing { inserted" in DeclarePairedDelimiter

Tags: errors, delimiters

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\left|}{\right|}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\absl}{\lvert}{\rvert}

\begin{document}
    $\abs{\cdot}$
    
    $\absl{\cdot}$
\end{document}
```

The output is as expected:

[image]

However, I have the following error with regard to the usage of `\abs`:

```
Missing { inserted. $\abs{\cdot}
Missing { inserted. $\abs{\cdot}
Missing } inserted. $\abs{\cdot}
Missing } inserted. $\abs{\cdot}$
```

Why? How to prevent this?

Comment: It was never stated that you could use `\left` and `\right` within `DeclarePairedDelimiter`, was it? Just use the second definition

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\DeclarePairedDelimiter with \left and \right](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225562/declarepaireddelimiter-with-left-and-right)

Comment: @user202729 Yes it does answer my question partly. Is there a way I can achieve resizing without going through the rigmarole that egreg uses in their answer, that uses `\left|`?

Comment: What do you mean? Just copy paste it in

Comment: Alternatively use this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23182/250119 , might be easier to understand

Comment: @StefanPinnow That's what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: @Atom but then you lose the benefit of the ams command, and get the poorer horizontal spacing of left-right